# Create and access properties in enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a situation with an enum in Java. I have created an enum as follows;

```
@Getter
public enum TransliterationKeys {
     FULL_NAME("Full Name of the Applicant"),

     NAME_TO_BE_INCLUDE_IN_IC("Name to be included IC"),

     GENDER("Gender");

     private final String transliterationKey;

     TransliterationKeys(String transliterationKey) {
           this.transliterationKey = transliterationKey;
     }
}
```

In here I can access the value of any enum property as;

```
String name = TransliterationKeys.FULL_NAME.getTransliterationKey()
```

I want to change that enum class to access it as this. I want to access another enum inside that enum.

```
int nameId = TransliterationKeys.FULL_NAME.ENGLISH
int nameId = TransliterationKeys.FULL_NAME.TAMIL
```

Is there any way achieve this.

So as I want after modifying the enum, it will look like this as I think (note: my imagination)

```
@Getter
public enum TransliterationKeys {
     FULL_NAME(ENLIGH(1), TAMIL(2)),

     NAME_TO_BE_INCLUDE_IN_IC(ENLIGH(6), TAMIL(7)),

     GENDER(ENLIGH(4), TAMIL(5));
}
```

Comment: No. You can't nest enums in Java.